# hive/impala metadata refresh

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

Does `REFRESH table` command refresh the metadata in Impala when a partition location is changed in Hive?

I am changing the Hive table partition location using

```
ALTER TABLE db.table partition(key=value1, key2=value2) set location='path'
```

After that, I am running `REFRESH db.table` in Impala which is not updating metadata. If I run `INVALIDATE METADATA` it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Impala JIRA-4364](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-4364) open for that. However its been in product backlog since 2017, so currently `INVALIDATE METADATA` is the only workaround.

**UPDATE:** This has been fixed in Impala 4.0 (see same JIRA link above).

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you perform msck repair after loading into the Hive partition instance.

Afterwards, you can invalidate the metadata for the DB in which the table resides in Impala shell/UI

Comment: Invalidate is working. Refresh is not working. Trying to avoid Invalidate as it is expensive operation.

Comment: try refresh table; It's less expensive